# Why does the PATH variable include invalid directory paths in Fedora 25?

Tags: fedora, environment-variables, path

I am using fedora 25, my system in up to date to current date. Then type the command :

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/blackswan/.local/bin:/home/blackswan/bin
```

The out put has given. Then i have tried to go every folder that have shown in the environment variable. But i have unable to locate the last two directories. I have not changed the variable before, i have seen the variable for the first time. Now my question is if i have not changed it before how some invalid directories has  added here? Is it safe to remove those directories or is there any problem if i don't remove them?

Answer (score 2):

The file `/etc/skel/.bash_profile` is copied to `~/.bash_profile` when a new user is created.

On Fedora 25, I believe that this file contains the statement

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
```

The Fedora people apparently thought that these two locations are commonly used for private executables, and therefore made it the default to add them to the `PATH`.

You should be able to locate this line in your `~/.bash_profile` file and either comment it out or delete it. There is nothing wrong with doing this if you are not using those two directories (or if they don't exist).

Reference: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=310005 (last post in the thread, at the bottom)